# :-1: error: The Qt version is invalid: qmake does not exist or is not executable

Tags: qt, versions, qmake

When I do deploy to Ubuntu device debug I get the following message

```
:-1: error: The Qt version is invalid: qmake does not exist or is not executable
```

Comment: This is very unhelpful and does not provide information that will help us solve your problem

Comment: You have to give a lot mor information, but but did you install qmake gcc qt devel packages?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

And then create manual *Qt version*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you need QT4 or QT5 , install `qtbase5-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

and/or install `qtbase4-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase4-dev
```

respectively...